# Code causing Servo motor not to work!

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, arduino-motor-shield, code-review, stepper

My sketch is compiling and loading, but when the program runs, the Servo motor does not work. The buttons work, the LED light works, Piezo buzzer plays the melody, the Stepper motor works but not consistently. The Servo/Stepper motors and LED worked until I introduced the code for the Piezo buzzer to play a melody. I'm new to programming and want to learn from others in a constructive way. I hope this forum is a place where people at all levels of knowledge and experience want to lend a helping hand. Here is my sketch:

```
#include <Stepper.h>
#include <Servo.h>

/*ARDUINO MOTOR SHIELD
 * The pin breakdown is as follows:
 * Function          Channel A   Channel B
 * Direction         Digital 12  Digital 13
 * Speed (PWM)       Digital 3   Digital 11
 * Brake             Digital 9   Digital 8
 * Current Sensing   Analog 0  Analog 1
 */

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // 1.8 deg. step angle(200 steps/360 deg. rev)
const int dirChA = 12;     // assigning name "dirChA" to pin 12
const int dirChB = 13;     // assigning name "dirChB" to pin 13 
const int pwmChA = 3;      // assigning name "pwmChA" to pin 3 
const int pwmChB = 11;     // assigning name "pwmChB" to pin 11 
const int brkChA = 9;      // assigning name "brkChA" to pin 9
const int brkChB = 8;      // assigning name "brkChB" to pin 8

const int srvoMtr = 10;    // assigning name "srvoMtr" to pin 10

const int pButton1 = 4;    // assigning name "pButton1" to pin 4 
const int pButton2 = 5;    // assigning name "pButton2" to pin 5
const int pButton3 = 6;    // assigning name "pButton3" to pin 6
const int pButton4 = 7;    // assigning name "pButton4" to pin 7

const int ledLight = 2;    // assigning name "ledLight" to pin 2

Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, dirChA, dirChB);  // initialize the stepper library on pins 12 & 13
Servo myServo;  // initialize the servo library to logical name myServo

int pButton1State = 0;     // variable for reading the pButton1 state as LOW or HIGH
int pButton2State = 0;     // variable for reading the pButton2 state as LOW or HIGH
int pButton3State = 0;     // variable for reading the pButton3 state as LOW or HIGH
int pButton4State = 0;     // variable for reading the pButton4 state as LOW or HIGH

int pButtonFlag = 0;     // variable for when button 1 has been pressed and released

int myServoPos = 0;      // variable for when servo has reached it's position
int myServoFlag = 0;     // variable for servo when any of the 4 pButton are pressed

int tonePin = A3;        //variable for buzzer

void midi() {
    tone(tonePin, 233, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 412.325976562);
    delay(458.139973958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 155, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(236.303776042);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 155, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(236.303776042);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(236.303776042);
    tone(tonePin, 233, 555.555);
    delay(617.283333333);
    delay(77.1604166667);
    tone(tonePin, 233, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 412.325976562);
    delay(458.139973958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 155, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(236.303776042);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 155, 99.8262890625);
    delay(110.918098958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(4.82252604167);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(236.303776042);
    tone(tonePin, 184, 203.992851562);
    delay(226.658723958);
    delay(236.303776042);
    tone(tonePin, 233, 555.555);
}

void setup() {
// Serial.begin(9600);   // initialize the serial port for messaging & troubleshooting

 // 1 Stepper Motor
 pinMode(dirChA, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 12 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(dirChA, LOW);   //initialize pin 12 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)

 pinMode(dirChB, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 13 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(dirChB, LOW);   //intialize pin 13 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)

 pinMode(pwmChA, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 3 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);   //intialize pin 3 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)

 pinMode(pwmChB, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 11 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);   //intialize pin 11 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)

 pinMode(brkChA, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 9 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(brkChA, LOW);   //intialize pin 9 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)

 pinMode(brkChB, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 8 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(brkChB, LOW);   //intialize pin 8 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)

 myStepper.setSpeed(60);   // set the speed of the stepper motor to 60 RPM

 // 4 Push Buttons
 pinMode(pButton1, INPUT);   // initialize pin 4 as an INPUT
 digitalWrite(pButton1, LOW);   // initialize pin 4 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)

 pinMode(pButton2, INPUT);   // initialize pin 5 as an INPUT
 digitalWrite(pButton2, LOW);   // initialize pin 5 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)

 pinMode(pButton3, INPUT);   // initialize pin 6 as an INPUT
 digitalWrite(pButton3, LOW);   // initialize pin 6 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)

 pinMode(pButton4, INPUT);   // initialize pin 7 as an INPUT
 digitalWrite(pButton4, LOW);   // initialize pin 7 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)

 // 1 Led Light
 pinMode(ledLight, OUTPUT);   // initialize pin 2 as an OUTPUT
 digitalWrite(ledLight, LOW);   // initialize pin 2 as LOW (pin voltage is 0 V)
}

void loop() {
  //Read button state (pressed or not pressed?)
  pButton1State = digitalRead(pButton1);   // read the state of pButton1 as LOW or HIGH
  pButton2State = digitalRead(pButton2);   // read the state of pButton2 as LOW or HIGH
  pButton3State = digitalRead(pButton3);   // read the state of pButton3 as LOW or HIGH
  pButton4State = digitalRead(pButton4);   // read the state of pButton4 as LOW or HIGH

  // check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the pbuttonState is HIGH:
  if (pButton1State == HIGH) {
     pButtonFlag=1;  // change pButton1Flag variable
  }
     if (pButtonFlag == 1){
        digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        myStepper.step(40);          // step forward 40 steps to position 1
        digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    //disable power to stepper

        myServoFlag=1;             // change ServoFlag variable to dispense chocolate

        if (myServoFlag == 1){
           myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
           for (myServoPos = 0; myServoPos <= 100; myServoPos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 100 degrees in steps of 1 degree
               myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'myServoPos'
               delay(15);                    // waits 15 milliseconds for the servo to reach the position
           }
           myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
           delay(2000); // hold position OPEN for 2 sec

           myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
           for (myServoPos = 100; myServoPos >= 0; myServoPos -= 1) { // goes from 100 degrees to 0 degrees in steps of 1 degree
               myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos
               delay(15);
           }
           myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10
        }    

        myServoFlag=0;         // changes myServoFlag value back to zero (0)     
        digitalWrite(ledLight, HIGH);   // turn on light to indicate chocolate is dispensed
        midi();

        digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        myStepper.step(-40);          // step backward 40 steps to position 0
        digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    // disable power to stepper

        digitalWrite(pButton1, LOW);   // initialize pin 4 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)
        digitalWrite(ledLight, LOW);   // turns off light to indicate the sequence is completed

        pButtonFlag=0;                // changes pButtonFlat value back to zero (0)
        delay(2000); 
     }

  // position 2
  if (pButton2State == HIGH) {
     pButtonFlag=1;  // change pButtonFlag variable
  }
     if (pButtonFlag == 1){
        digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        myStepper.step(80);          // step forward 80 steps to position 2
        digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    //disable power to stepper
        delay(2000);

        myServoFlag=1;    // change ServoFlag variable to dispense chocolate

        if (myServoFlag == 1){
           myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
           for (myServoPos = 0; myServoPos <= 100; myServoPos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 100 degrees in steps of 5 degrees
               myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'myServoPos'
               delay(15);                    // waits 15 milliseconds for the servo to reach the position
           }
           myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
           delay(2000);

           myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
           for (myServoPos = 100; myServoPos >= 0; myServoPos -= 1) { // goes from 100 degrees to 0 degrees in steps of 1 degree
               myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos
               delay(15);
           }
           myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
        }    
        myServoFlag=0;                // changes myServoFlag value back to zero (0)     
        digitalWrite(ledLight, HIGH);    // turn on light to indicate chocolate is dispensed
        midi();

        digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
        myStepper.step(-80);          // step backward 80 steps to position 0
        digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
        digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    //disable power to stepper

        digitalWrite(pButton2, LOW);   // initialize pin 5 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)
        digitalWrite(ledLight, LOW);   // turns off light to indicate the sequence is completed

        pButtonFlag=0;   // changes pButton2Flag value back to zero (0)
        delay(2000); 
    }

    // position 3
    if (pButton3State == HIGH) {
       pButtonFlag=1;   // change pButtonFlag variable
    }
       if (pButtonFlag == 1){
          digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          myStepper.step(120);          // step forward 120 steps to position 3
          digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    //disable power to stepper
          delay(2000);

          myServoFlag=1;   // change ServoFlag variable to dispense chocolate

          if (myServoFlag == 1){
             myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
             for (myServoPos = 0; myServoPos <= 100; myServoPos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 100 degrees in steps of 5 degrees
                 myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'myServoPos'
                 delay(15);                    // waits 3 sec for the servo to reach the position
             }
             myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
             delay(2000);

             myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
             for (myServoPos = 100; myServoPos >= 0; myServoPos -= 1) { // goes from 100 degrees to 0 degrees in steps of 1 degree
               myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos
               delay(15);
             }
             myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
          }    
          myServoFlag=0;                // changes myServoFlag value back to zero (0)     
          digitalWrite(ledLight, HIGH);   // turn on light to indicate chocolate is dispensed
          midi();

          digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          myStepper.step(-120);         // step backward 120 steps to position 0
          digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    // disable power to stepper

          digitalWrite(pButton3, LOW);   // initialize pin 6 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)
          digitalWrite(ledLight, LOW);   // turns off light to indicate the sequence is completed

          pButtonFlag=0;   // changes pButton3Flag value back to zero (0)
          delay(2000); 
     }
    // position 4
    if (pButton4State == HIGH) {
       pButtonFlag=1;   // change pButtonFlag variable
    }
       if (pButtonFlag == 1){
          digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          myStepper.step(160);          // step forward 160 steps to position 3
          digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    //disable power to stepper
          delay(2000);

          myServoFlag=1;   // change ServoFlag variable to dispense chocolate
          Serial.println("\nServo Flag = 1 - Dispense Chocolate");

          if (myServoFlag == 1){
             myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
             for (myServoPos = 0; myServoPos <= 100; myServoPos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 100 degrees in steps of 5 degrees
                 myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'myServoPos'
                 delay(15);                    // waits 3 sec for the servo to reach the position
             }
             myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
             delay(2000);

             myServo.attach(srvoMtr);   // attaches the servo library to pin 10
             for (myServoPos = 100; myServoPos >= 0; myServoPos -= 1) { // goes from 100 degrees to 0 degrees in steps of 1 degree
               myServo.write(myServoPos);    // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos
               delay(15);
             }
             myServo.detach();   // detaches the servo library from pin 10   
          }    
          myServoFlag=0;   // changes myServoFlag value back to zero (0)     
          digitalWrite(ledLight, HIGH);   // turn on light to indicate chocolate is dispensed
          midi();

          digitalWrite(pwmChA, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, HIGH);   // enable power to stepper
          myStepper.step(-160);         // step backward 160 steps to position 0
          digitalWrite(pwmChA, LOW);    // disable power to stepper
          digitalWrite(pwmChB, LOW);    // disable power to stepper

          digitalWrite(pButton3, LOW);   // initialize pin 6 as LOW (pin voltage less than 1.5V)
          digitalWrite(ledLight, LOW);   // turns off light to indicate the sequence is completed

          pButtonFlag=0;   // changes pButton3Flag value back to zero (0)
          delay(2000);          
       }
}
```

Comment: As expected, you want to control servo with pin 3,  but it’s been explained in other questions that ‘tone()’ interferes with PWM on pins 3 and 11. Servos are controlled by PWM signals.

Comment: I'm using a motor shield. I'm using Pin 10 to signal the Servo. Shouldn't that work? Pin 3 & 11 are being used by the Stepper

Comment: `Code causing Servo motor not to work!`   ..... disconnect the servo from the arduino ... i bet that it still will not be working .... it is not the code causing it not to work

Comment: @jsotola it's exactly the code causing it not to work

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco, that is not true .... you do not require any code at all for the motor to be inoperative  ...... `the code is not causing the motor to work` is the correct statement ...... in other words, the code is not making the motor run

Answer (score 0):

As already reported in the comments, the `Tone` library uses Timer2 an hardware module of the Atmega328P microcontroller, which is also in charge of generating the PWM signal on pins 3 and 11.
As pins 3 and 11 are both used by your code to pilot the servo motor, it should be of no surprise the motor starts to behave erratically once you added the code to play tones on the buzzer.

A solution would be not to use the PWM pins 3 and 11 as PWM (you can still use those, just not to generate PWM signals)

That is clearly reported in the docs:

> PWM frequencies are tied together in pairs of pins. If one in a pair is changed, the other is also changed to match:
>
> - Pins 5 and 6 are paired on timer0
> - Pins 9 and 10 are paired on timer1
> - Pins 3 and 11 are paired on timer2

And also:

> Use of the tone() function will interfere with PWM output on pins 3 and 11 (on boards other than the Mega).